# How do I reset the input language to English when I can't read the current language?

Tags: settings, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, factory-reset

I have a **Nexus 4** with the latest OS.

I accidentally set the input to **Arabic**.

Now I don't know how to reset to **English**.

I tried re-booting but it did not revert to **English**.

I would like to avoid a factory reset, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered how to do this.

The icons for the various functions remain the same.

I went into

1. **Settings** (cogwheel icon) then
2. **Language & input** (white square with black A)
3. Top item in this menu is **Language**

I tapped this item and was presented with the normal list of languages, 
each in its own font.